# If to use async in a synchronous method that yield return's?

Tags: c#, async-await, yield-return

I'm trying to find a an appropriate method to validate POST and PUT requests. I came up with 2 methods, 'Validate()' and 'ValidateAsync(). I'm just not sure which to use.

---

**'Validate()'**, a synchronous method, returning 'yield return', and with async.Result (no await) queries in it, which from my understanding, is the same as synchronous (unless I'm wrong and it is asynchronous):

```cs
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(Entity entity)
{
    // ** NOTE: NO AWAIT AND USING '.RESULT' TO GET VALUE.**
    var idExistsAsync = repo.ExistsAsync(e => e.Id == entity.Id).Result;
    if (!idExistsAsync)
        yield return new ValidationResult("Id does not exist");

    // ** NOTE: NO AWAIT AND USING '.RESULT' TO GET VALUE.**
    var userNameExistsAsync = repo.ExistsAsync(e => e.UserName == entity.UserName).Result;
    if (!userNameExistsAsync)
        yield return new ValidationResult("UserName does not exist");
}
```

- In the above example, would it even matter if I use ExistsAsync().Result or just use 
  a non async version, Exsits().

```cs
    var idExists = repo.Exists(e => e.Id == entity.Id);
    var userNameExists = repo.Exists(e => e.UserName == entity.UserName);
```

---

**'ValidateAsync()'**, an async method, but without 'yield return', adding the 'errors' to a list and returning the List():

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<ValidationResult>> ValidateAsync(Entity entity)
{
    var result = new List<ValidationResult>();

    var idExistsAsync = await repo.ExistsAsync(e => e.Id == entity.Id);
    if (!idExistsAsync)
        result.Add(new ValidationResult("Id does not exist"));

    var userNameExistsAsync = await repo.ExistsAsync(e => e.UserName == entity.UserName);
    if (!userNameExistsAsync)
        result.Add(new ValidationResult("UserName does not exist"));

    return result;
}
```

---

Q: What is the best approach? Validate() or ValidateAsync()? If Validate(), using ExistsAsync().Result or Exists()?

Thank you.

Comment: The main difference is that the sync version is yielding values while the async version collects the results. Don't try to mix `async/await` in your first example, you'll just end up with a deadlock. `async/await` and enumerators, `Yield`, don't mix. Pick the one that suits your needs if you can collect results and return them, use the second, if you want to yield values use the first.

Comment: This is an opinionated question, but since you need to wait to get both results to return to the client, the second version makes more sense. (and try to **always** avoid `.Result`)

Comment: These commenters are correct. Do not use `.Result` in an asynchronous workflow. Why not? Because this can happen: (1) we have a task that is not complete (2) it is scheduled to execute *on this thread* in the future because it has posted a message to the work queue that executes its work, (3) we call `.Result`, which blocks the current thread until the task completes.  But the task will never complete because *this blocked thread is the thread that is going to complete it*.

Comment: I agree that it is irritating that you cannot mix the two kinds of coroutines in C#; it would be nice if you could `await` and `yield` in the same method. There will be some work done on this in C# 8; see Mads' talk about `IAsyncEnumerable` for details.